# How is dividend of my owned stocks calculated?

Tags: stocks, dividends, ex-dividend-date, stock-dividend

Say I bought a stock on Jan 5 and sold it on Sept 3 in the same year, how do the company pay the dividend?

What if I sold it on Jan 6?